# Search PHP array of arrays using an array value and then update other array values in the matching array

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have a string stored in WordPress MySQL database Meta field as serialized string of array of arrays like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"B";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:6:"bbbbbb";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:12:"bbbbbbbbbbbb";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:1;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"C";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:5:"ccccc";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:17:"ccccccccccccccccc";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:2;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"D";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:8:"dddddddd";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:1:"d";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:3;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"E";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:8:"eeeeeeee";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:30:"eeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}}
```

When I unserialize that string above it looks like this below...

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'B',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'bbbbbb',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'bbbbbbbbbbbb',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'C',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'ccccc',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'ccccccccccccccccc',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'D',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'dddddddd',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'd',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'ab-variation-letter' => 'E',
    'ab-variation-title' => 'eeeeeeee',
    'ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-' => 'eeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee',
    'ab-variation-conversion-count' => '',
    'ab-variation-views' => '',
    'ab-variation-start-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-end-date' => '',
    'ab-variation-winner' => '',
  ),
)
```

based on this array of arrays above.  I want to be able to search for the array that has `ab-variation-letter' => 'C'` and then be able to update any of the other array key values on that matching array.  When done I will need to re-serialize back into a string so I can save it back to the Database table again.

---

I want to build this PHP function below to be able to take my serialized string of array of arrays and search those arrays  for an array that has a key/value matching the passed in `$array_key` string and then update another keyvalue in that same array and then reserialize the whole thing again.

```
function updateAbTestMetaData($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $array_key, $new_value){

    //get serialized meta from DB
    $serialized_meta_data_string = 'a:4:{i:0;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"B";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:6:"bbbbbb";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:12:"bbbbbbbbbbbb";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:1;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"C";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:5:"ccccc";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:17:"ccccccccccccccccc";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:2;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"D";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:8:"dddddddd";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:1:"d";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:3;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"E";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:8:"eeeeeeee";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:30:"eeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}}';

    //un-serialize meta data string
    $meta_data_arrays = unserialize($serialized_meta_data_string);

    // search array of arrays $meta_data_arrays for array that has a key == $array_key // 'ab-variation-letter' === 'D'

    // update the value of any other key on that matching array

    // re-serialize all the data with the updated data

}
```

---

The end result should allow me to find the array with key `'ab-variation-letter' === 'C'` and update the key/value in that matching array with key `'ab-variation-title'` and update its current value from `'ccccc'` to `'new value'` and then re-serialize the whole entire array of arrays back into the original string with only the updated array data updated/

Comment: _then be able to update any of the other array key values on that matching array_ Not understand.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps throwing together a recursive function that can make use of calling itself could come in handy:

```
function replaceArrayKeyValue(array &$arr, $whereKey, $whereValue, $replacement) {
  $matched = false;
  $keys = array_keys($arr);

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++)
  {
    $key = $keys[$i];
    if (is_string($arr[$key])) {
      if ($key === $whereKey && $arr[$key] === $whereValue) {
        if (is_array($replacement)) {
          $arr = array_replace_recursive($arr, $replacement);
        } else {
          $arr[$key] = $replacement;
        }
        $matched = $key;
        break;
      }
    } else if (is_array($arr[$key])) {
      $m = replaceArrayKeyValue($arr[$key], $whereKey, $whereValue, $replacement);
      if ($m !== false) {
        $matched = $key.'.'.$m;
        break;
      }
    }
    unset($key);
  }

  unset($keys);
  return $matched;
}
```

With the above function, you pass through the source array (`$arr`), the key you're looking for (`$whereKey`), the value that it should match (`$whereValue`) and the replacement value (`$replacement`).

If `$replacement` is an array, I've got a `array_replace_recursive` in place to perform a recursive replacement, allowing you to pass in the changes you'd like to make to the array. For example, in your case:

```
$data = unserialize(...);
$matchedKey = replaceArrayKeyValue($data, 'ab-variation-letter', 'C', [
    'ab-variation-title' => 'My New Title'
]);
$serialized = serialize($data);
```

You could replace this with `array_recursive` if you're not wanting the changes to occur further down any nested child arrays.

When using this function, the `$data` array is modified directly. The result of the function is a joint string of the key path to that value, in this case:

```
echo $matchedKey; // Result: 1.ab-variation-letter
```

If you `echo print_r($data, true)`, you get the intended result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array( ... )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ab-variation-letter] => C
            [ab-variation-title] => My New Title
            [ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-] => ccccccccccccccccc
            [ab-variation-conversion-count] =>
            [ab-variation-views] =>
            [ab-variation-start-date] =>
            [ab-variation-end-date] =>
            [ab-variation-winner] =>
        )
    [2] => Array( ... )
    [3] => Array( ... )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after some playing around with this code below.  Open to other versions as well thanks

```
$serialized_meta_data_string = 'a:4:{i:0;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"B";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:6:"bbbbbb";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:12:"bbbbbbbbbbbb";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:1;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"C";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:5:"ccccc";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:17:"ccccccccccccccccc";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:2;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"D";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:8:"dddddddd";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:1:"d";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}i:3;a:8:{s:19:"ab-variation-letter";s:1:"E";s:18:"ab-variation-title";s:8:"eeeeeeee";s:28:"ab-variation-wysiwyg-editor-";s:30:"eeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee";s:29:"ab-variation-conversion-count";s:0:"";s:18:"ab-variation-views";s:0:"";s:23:"ab-variation-start-date";s:0:"";s:21:"ab-variation-end-date";s:0:"";s:19:"ab-variation-winner";s:0:"";}}';

$update_on_key = 'ab-variation-title';
$ab_version = 'C';
$new_value = 'new variation title on variation C';

$new_data = updateMetaArrayData($serialized_meta_data_string, $update_on_key, $ab_version, $new_value);

echo '<pre>';
echo $new_data;


function updateMetaArrayData($serialized_meta_data_string, $update_on_key, $ab_version, $new_value){
    $new_meta_data_arrays = array();

    //un-serialize meta data string
    $meta_data_arrays = unserialize($serialized_meta_data_string);

    foreach($meta_data_arrays as $key => $value){
        $new_meta_data_arrays[$key] = $value;
        if(isset($value['ab-variation-letter']) && $value['ab-variation-letter'] == $ab_version){
            $new_meta_data_arrays[$key][$update_on_key] = $new_value;
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($new_meta_data_arrays);

    $new_serialized_meta = serialize($new_meta_data_arrays);
    return $new_serialized_meta;
}
```